# I am working on a google app with the Gmail API and my IP is getting flagged for "Unusual Activity. How do I request Google to white list an IP?

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension that uses the Gmail API to sync emails. 
As I am testing, refreshing, changing code etc,  I often get a message that Google has detected Unusual Activity from my IP address, causing the entire office to have to enter CAPTCHAS to do any Google searches.

Today I actually had my test email account locked for one hour because I was requesting email too often.

Does anyone know of a way to ask Google to whitelist a specific IP for development?

EDIT* if you are going to downvote my question can you at least explain why?  I would like to be a good netizen but if you dont tell me what I am doing wrong you are part of the problem, not part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Google documents in their help article: "...we notify you about unusual account activity, such as sign-ins or password changes from unfamiliar locations and devices. **You can review this activity and confirm whether or not you actually took the action**."

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en

You might also check this article about "How to Turn Off a Gmail IP Address Tracker" at http://smallbusiness.chron.com/turn-off-gmail-ip-address-tracker-51241.html.

Comment: This isn't getting flagged inside of gmail, (the tab at security.google.com doesnt show the unusal activity, which is weird, you think it would,) rather it is flagging the entire network and blocking access from Google services.